# Dismissing ViewControllers in succession when Reachability changes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, reachability, dismiss

I am coding a game where the user can only play if there is an active internet connection. I want to dismiss all ViewControllers and get back to the login screen if the internet status changes. Here's the hierarchy:

My App Delegate show the LoginViewController by:

```
self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Here the user logs in. While logging in I check for connectivity and handle errors. If login is successful loginViewController presents mainViewController using

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.mainViewController animated:YES];
```

Then mainViewController presents other controllers, which can present other controllers and so on. The present and dismiss routine is working properly.

Now, if Reachability status changes, I want to display an alert and force the app to get back to the login screen. I know how to listen for these notification and take actions appropriately. It is well documented :)

How do I dismiss all view controllers until I land back in the login screen? Do I need to listen to the notification in all view controllers and dismiss them separately? Is there any way of catching the notification in a parent (like the app delegate) and dismissing all view controllers from there (without holding a reference to all of them beforehand)?

Obviously, I'm not using a navigationController so

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

is not possible.

Edit: Alternately, I can dismiss and release everything and start from scratch, like if the application is started new. Is this a better approach? How exactly do I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I solved it. Simply calling

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

on the loginViewController dismisses main view controller and all controllers above on the stack.

Comment: Does the notification not fire when in fact it should, or does it fire unnecessarily when it shouldn't? For me the former is still manageable, but the latter would destroy the app experience.

Comment: both..Id get into specifics but it tends to cause flame wars from people who think it works, it doesnt, search SO there are many many discussions regarding reachability.

Comment: Deprecated... use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` instead.